# Add a dot in “MA Thesis” in biblatex’s @masterthesis entry

Tags: biblatex, naming

in output I see "MA Thesis" however I want to have "MA. Thesis". How one can put a dot after "MA"?

I am using `numeric` style. I looked though the file `biblatex.def` and I can see some `\map` sententences which I think  `@masterthesis` is mapped to `@thesis`. Not sure where that "MA" is hidden.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct way is to use the `@thesis` entry type with a "mathesis" `type` field and to redefine the `mathesis` bibliography string (which is, in its non-abbreviated and abbreviated variants, hidden in `english.lbx`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  mathesis = {MA\adddot\addabbrvspace Thesis},
}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@thesis{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  type = {mathesis},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Now I can find it in the `biblatex` manual too. But believe me it was not that straight forward. I wished there existed a short introduction in the beginning of the manual, explaining the technical terms and highlighting where to find what in the big book.